# Difference between the excitation current of a transformer and the magnetizing current

Tags: transformer

What is the difference between the magnetizing current of a transformer and excitation current?
The doubt came to me when I was reading a book and it explained the real model of the transformer and considered the excitation current as a Fourier series of the sum of the third, fifth harmonic components etc... But I know that the inrush current is composed of many second harmonic components. So is the inrush current the magnetizing current or the excitation current?

Comment: You want to know the difference between magnetizing current and magnetizing current? They're the same thing--you just said the same thing twice.

Comment: I don't know where I was thinking, I fixed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *So is the inrush current the magnetizing current or the excitation
> current?*

It's the **magnetization current** reaching a high enough level so as to cause core saturation problems. That in turn causes an increase in the magnetization current (a runaway effect) and, in some circumstances this can create the situation where a massive pulse of current is see for a short time over a few cycles of AC. Inrush current is made worse if the transformer is connected to the AC line when voltage passes through zero: -

[image]

The above picture ([from here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/532622/does-turning-on-inductive-load-ex-ac-motor-at-peak-input-voltage-reduce-inrus/532626#532626)) isn't indicating a saturation problem; it's just showing that the peak of inrush current (even on a perfect transformer) can be double what is seen in normal operation. This of course only becomes a problem when the core saturates and magnetization current sky-rockets.

Here is an example of the potentially sky-rocketing problems with magnetization current from [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer) on transformers: -

[image]

Hopefully you can see that although the flux appears to be sinusoidal, the primary magnetization current is reaching quite high and badly distorted peaks.

---

The difference between **excitation current** and **magnetization current** is subtle and maybe not that well-defined. In the main magnetization current is what creates flux in the core and this numerically forms most of what the excitation current is. The remainder is usually taken to mean core losses.

Comment: I think I get it, would an excitation current be a portion of the current needed to create a magnetizing current?

Comment: Excitation current  = magnetization current + core loss currents @Dragnovith - some people may define it differently but, that's how it mainly appears to be defined. Some people (sometimes) call magnetization current the excitation current but, I think that's just a simplification when core losses are assumed to be very small or insignificant.

Comment: I would also add that when we talk about magnetization current we mean the current that produces the changing magnetic flux in the core that induces the secondary voltage.

Answer (score 0):

When a transformer is connected to its supply without load applied, there is a small current that circulate. This small current is called the excitation current.

The excitation current is composed of two components: a resistive one and an inductive one. The resistive one is called core losses, the inductive one is called magnetizing current. This current is function of the core and winding physical properties and does not vary with the load.

To your question: Excluding the load current, the transformer initial inrush current is the magnetizing current to energize the core.

Comment: @relayman357, noted, I've corrected my answer. However the question was primarily about the difference between the two type of current. May be title of the question should be modified to reflect the intent.